# Error while Archiving when added Firebase and Admob to SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios, firebase, sprite-kit, admob

This is very strange to me. or may be I am missing something how Firebase admob works with SpriteKit Games.

I have successfully added Firebase and Admob to my SpriteKit game. I have been testing my game all this evening. When I am done with all changes. I am Archiving to send the build to itunesconnect. I see following screen as its not able to see GoogleMobileAds framwork. 
[image: errir]

Following is my pods file :

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'Appirater', '~> 2.0' #Remimder to rate app
pod 'apptentive-ios', '~> 3.1' #rating and feedback system

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Comment: note sure what firebase is, but those types of errors occor when the framework is not being linked with the the rest of the project.  Check your build settings to make sure that it is being linked